# EWS Managed API versions work different ways?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchangewebservices, office-addins

I have an old and a new app. In both I create appointments in calendars and add extended properties with a custom namespace (Guid) via EWS Managed API. The server is the same.

The old app is running under .NET 4.7.1 and uses Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices (version 1.2), while the new app is running under .NET 6 and uses Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard (version 1.1.3).

I use the below code to add a new property in both apps

```
var epd = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(EWS_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES_GUID, "SFRECID", MapiPropertyType.String);
NewEWSAppointment.SetExtendedProperty(epd, Item.GetItemByName(epd.Name).Value);
```

If I create the appointment in the old app then OutlookSpy (5.0) lists my properties correctly.

[image]

If I run the new app then I cannot see them in OutlookSpy,

[image]

but I can find the newly created appointment with the same app and the extended properties are returned correctly.

Is there any difference between the full framework implementation of the EWS API and the NetStandard version? How could I change the new app to work the same way as the old? I want OutlookSpy to show them the same way, because there are other apps depending on these properties.

Update: Here is a screenshot of the created appointment in the calendar.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are the properties still missing if you (as a test) turn caching mode off?

Comment: what your using in .net standard would be a port of the EWS Managed API if what Dimtry has suggested doesn't work its probably a bug in the port. You can enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications or check the request with fiddler what you should see in the underlying request is the props being sent to the server. Usually you just need to patch the repo in these instance and recompile your library.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, Thank you for the tip. For some reason I cannot turn off the cache just set it down to 1 month... Maybe I try to do it at the wrong place (under change account) in Outlook. But I think clicking the [Send/Receive All Folders] button does the same. No success this way, after multiple Outlook restart and forced sync cycles.

Comment: @GlenScales, Yes, it is a port. Thanks for the idea. Although I can retrieve the extended properties from the server at a later time (in my new app), s.g. makes Outlook Spy think that those properties are not there - while they are actually there. So there may be a difference between the two libs.

Comment: I have done some further tests, and it looks like there may be s.g. in Outlook Spy because both my old and new apps can see the properties the same way (using different EWS libraries), just the Outlook Spy can not.

Comment: Your second screenshot show way too few named properties for an appointment residing in an Exchange mailbox. Are you sure you are looking at the right appointment and it is not an instance of a recurring appointment?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. No recursion.  Please see my edit on the post, I have added the screenshot of the created appointment.

Comment: I'd suggest you compare the two requests when you create the appointment old and new it maybe something else in the new request that's affecting the appointment creation.  If it get fixed later that could be the calendar assistant repairing the appointment on the server side

Comment: After a day putting the problem away - because of other urgent tasks - I find that the extended properties now magically appear in the newly created appointment. No change in the app, just multiple restarts of Outlook. I suspect that this was indeed some caching problem (suggested by Dmitry), but I do not know why turning off the caching in Outlook did not affect the behavior immediately - and why it did after a day or two. Thank you both for helping me with suggestions.